# Graphon convergence of uniform weighted graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I have a question that I need at some point my research. Suppose that the upper-triangular entries of an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ are i.i.d. Uniform$(0,1)$. Does the weighted graph with weighted adjacency $A$ converge to a graphon as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and if so, how does the limiting graphon look like? Also, can the uniform distribution be generalized to some other distributions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a *graphon*?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon